# Remove not_exist_already node from mnesia cluster(scheme)

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have a bad node (it doesn't exist) in the mnesia cluster data when I get:

```
> mnesia:system_info(db_nodes)
[bad@node, ...]
```

How do I remove it from the cluster?

I tried:

```
> mnesia:del_table_copy(scheme, bad@node).
{aborted,{not_active,"All replicas on diskfull nodes are not active yet"...
```

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

**Update. Before remove node from schema we need to stop mnesia on it**

Comment: Generally, IIRC, if there is a node that is down or not active, Mnesia wont bother making any kind of connection or syncing until it comes back up. If there any reason why you have to remove it from the cluster instead of ignoring it? If you need to remove it, could you clarify as to why?

Comment: I planned chnage short node names to long, and I afaid this bad nodes will be troubles. Am I wrong?

Comment: I am not 100% sure on this, but I don't think it will be an issue. I believe that mnesia will check to see if the bad node is up, it will not be able to connect to it, so it will just ignore it. So that would be my advice. However, if I am wrong, (which may be the case), we can try to figure it out.

Comment: I'm amazed at the popularity of this question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819928/how-do-i-remove-an-extra-node

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem years ago. What you are trying to do is remove an offline node, which as far as I am aware was impossible in earlier versions of mnesia.

You can however connect to the cluster using a dummy node named `bad@node`, and started with a tweaked `system.config` of the original clustered node. Once its online remove from the cluster.